# How To Save Data From Remote APIs To ACF?

Tags: custom-field, database, advanced-custom-fields, api

I've been attempting to ingest remote data from an api partner into Wordpress. To data I've used wpallimport plugin, but it's quite limited.

How would one connect with a remote api and then save the data to a an ACF field either one time or periodically?

I've test out `wp_remote_get($apiUrl);` and even [created a POC](https://utility.report) but saving the data to the WP database has not been successful yet.

Comment: there's no code to work with in your question, can you share what you did? Note that ACF and other 3rd party plugins are offtopic here, you can ask how to store things in post meta, but you can't ask how to store ACF fields specifically, you'd need to ask in an ACF community for the specifics, especially since ACF fields can have internal structure

Comment: It could be any custom field, not necessity acf. Re code: I guess I’m trying to find the right method. Is that not an appropriate question?

Comment: can you share the code you've been working with so far? You mentioned you had a proof of concept, and have made attempts to save the data, but I can't see any code to work with in your question. Use the edit link to add the code